'from' value in the 'query' action inputs is of type 'Object'. The value must be an array
I have this Filter Array action:-

The outputs(FomrJsonAddedValue) will have this format:
{
    "OOH.2m2.2024.7.1085": {
        "OOH_media_list": [
            {
                "Network": "Flawless A",
                "Amount": "10500.000",
                "Duration": "2 week",
                "of_Faces": "25",
                "Start_Date": "29-Jul-2024",
                "End_Date": "11-Aug-2024",
                "type": "Out_Of_Home",
                "Delivery Date": "29-Jul-2024"
            },
            {
                "Network": "Flawless B",
                "Amount": "10500.000",
                "Duration": "2 week",
                "of_Faces": "25",
                "Start_Date": "29-Jul-2024",
                "End_Date": "11-Aug-2024",
                "type": "Out_Of_Home",
                "Delivery Date": "29-Jul-2024"
            },
            {
                "Network": "Velvet A",
                "Amount": "19000.000",
                "Duration": "2 week",
                "of_Faces": "50",
                "Start_Date": "29-Jul-2024",
                "End_Date": "11-Aug-2024",
                "type": "Out_Of_Home",
                "Delivery Date": "29-Jul-2024"
            },
            {
                "Network": "Velvet B",
                "Amount": "19000.000",
                "Duration": "2 week",
                "of_Faces": "50",
                "Start_Date": "29-Jul-2024",
                "End_Date": "11-Aug-2024",
                "type": "Out_Of_Home",
                "Delivery Date": "29-Jul-2024"
            }
        ],
        "Email": "******",
        "Category": [],
        "Sales Person Email": "*****",
        "Contract Number": "OOH.2m2.2024.7.1085",
        "Client Name": "MindShare",
        "Sector": null,
        "Financial_Accountant_Email": "******",
        "Tax_Registration_Number": "16664159",
        "Blue_River_No": "P.OOH.2m2.2024.7.1101",
        "Contact": [
            "Ms. R****"
        ],
        "Brand": "Arab Bank",
        "OOH_price_list": {
            "Net_Total": "50150.000",
            "Grand_Total": "58174.000",
            "Sales_Tax": "16.00",
            "Total": "59000.000",
            "DIscount": "15.00",
            "Amount_in_Words": "Fifty Eight Thousand One Hundred Seventy Four"
        },
        "BR_price_list": null,
        "blue_river_list": [],
        "Financial_Accountant_Name": "Ahmad Awwad",
        "Select_Customer_Type": "Agency",
        "No_Of_Faces_Production": null,
        "No of Faces": "150",
        "Sales Person Name": "D***"
    },
    "OOH.2m2.2024.7.1120": {
        "OOH_media_list": [
            {
                "Network": "Flawless C",
                "Amount": "5250.000",
                "Duration": "1 week",
                "of_Faces": "25",
                "Start_Date": "30-Jul-2024",
                "End_Date": "05-Aug-2024",
                "type": "Out_Of_Home",
                "Delivery Date": "30-Jul-2024"
            },
            {
                "Network": "Velvet Booster B",
                "Amount": "14250.000",
                "Duration": "1 week",
                "of_Faces": "75",
                "Start_Date": "31-Jul-2024",
                "End_Date": "06-Aug-2024",
                "type": "Out_Of_Home",
                "Delivery Date": "31-Jul-2024"
            }
        ],
        "Email": "****",
        "Category": [],
        "Sales Person Email": "****",
        "Contract Number": "OOH.2m2.2024.7.1120",
        "Client Name": "MindShare",
        "Sector": null,
        "Financial_Accountant_Email": "***",
        "Tax_Registration_Number": "16664159",
        "Blue_River_No": null,
        "Contact": [
            "Ms. Rana Elayyan"
        ],
        "Brand": "Mercedes ",
        "OOH_price_list": {
            "Net_Total": "16575.000",
            "Grand_Total": "19227.000",
            "Sales_Tax": "16.00",
            "Total": "19500.000",
            "DIscount": "15.00",
            "Amount_in_Words": "Nineteen Thousand Two Hundred Twenty Seven"
        },
        "BR_price_list": null,
        "blue_river_list": [],
        "Financial_Accountant_Name": "****",
        "Select_Customer_Type": "Agency",
        "No_Of_Faces_Production": null,
        "No of Faces": "100",
        "Sales Person Name": "*****"
    }
}

but the Filter Array will raise this error:-

any advice?
Thanks

"Filter array" action expects "Array" ([]) as an input while you are trying to use "Object" ({}) as input. What exactly are you trying to do with JSON output using Filter array action?

@GaneshSanap-MVP i want to select/filter the items from the JSON which have "Contract Number" = null..

@GaneshSanap-MVP in the sample i provided all items have values inside the ""contract Number",,, but some items have "Contract Number" = null and i want to build an array for those items from the original array

@GaneshSanap-MVP are you able to advice further?

After adjusting the supplied JSON, was able to make it work. Please see the revised JSON and Power Automate. I've added [ID] property to store the first value of the original JSON.
Also, note that Filer array expect an array for which JSON must begins with a [ and end with a ] like
[ { },{ },{ },... ]


And all properties name and type should be the same across all objects
Revised JSON
[
  {
    "ID": "OOH.2m2.2024.7.1085",
    "OOH_media_list": [
      {
        "Network": "Flawless A",
        "Amount": "10500.000",
        "Duration": "2 week",
        "of_Faces": "25",
        "Start_Date": "29-Jul-2024",
        "End_Date": "11-Aug-2024",
        "type": "Out_Of_Home",
        "Delivery Date": "29-Jul-2024"
      },
      {
        "Network": "Flawless B",
        "Amount": "10500.000",
        "Duration": "2 week",
        "of_Faces": "25",
        "Start_Date": "29-Jul-2024",
        "End_Date": "11-Aug-2024",
        "type": "Out_Of_Home",
        "Delivery Date": "29-Jul-2024"
      },
      {
        "Network": "Velvet A",
        "Amount": "19000.000",
        "Duration": "2 week",
        "of_Faces": "50",
        "Start_Date": "29-Jul-2024",
        "End_Date": "11-Aug-2024",
        "type": "Out_Of_Home",
        "Delivery Date": "29-Jul-2024"
      },
      {
        "Network": "Velvet B",
        "Amount": "19000.000",
        "Duration": "2 week",
        "of_Faces": "50",
        "Start_Date": "29-Jul-2024",
        "End_Date": "11-Aug-2024",
        "type": "Out_Of_Home",
        "Delivery Date": "29-Jul-2024"
      }
    ],
    "Email": "",
    "Category": [],
    "Sales Person Email": "",
    "Contract Number": "OOH.2m2.2024.7.1085",
    "Client Name": "MindShare",
    "Sector": null,
    "Financial_Accountant_Email": "",
    "Tax_Registration_Number": "16664159",
    "Blue_River_No": "P.OOH.2m2.2024.7.1101",
    "Contact": [
      "Ms. R****"
    ],
    "Brand": "Arab Bank ",
    "OOH_price_list": {
      "Net_Total": "50150.000",
      "Grand_Total": "58174.000",
      "Sales_Tax": "16.00",
      "Total": "59000.000",
      "DIscount": "15.00",
      "Amount_in_Words": "Fifty Eight Thousand One Hundred Seventy Four"
    },
    "BR_price_list": null,
    "blue_river_list": [],
    "Financial_Accountant_Name": "Ahmad Awwad",
    "Select_Customer_Type": "Agency",
    "No_Of_Faces_Production": null,
    "No of Faces": "150",
    "Sales Person Name": "D"
  },
  {
    "ID": "OOH.2m2.2024.7.1120",
    "OOH_media_list": [
      {
        "Network": "Flawless C",
        "Amount": "5250.000",
        "Duration": "1 week",
        "of_Faces": "25",
        "Start_Date": "30-Jul-2024",
        "End_Date": "05-Aug-2024",
        "type": "Out_Of_Home",
        "Delivery Date": "30-Jul-2024"
      },
      {
        "Network": "Velvet Booster B",
        "Amount": "14250.000",
        "Duration": "1 week",
        "of_Faces": "75",
        "Start_Date": "31-Jul-2024",
        "End_Date": "06-Aug-2024",
        "type": "Out_Of_Home",
        "Delivery Date": "31-Jul-2024"
      }
    ],
    "Email": "",
    "Category": [],
    "Sales Person Email": "",
    "Contract Number": "OOH.2m2.2024.7.1120",
    "Client Name": "MindShare",
    "Sector": null,
    "Financial_Accountant_Email": "",
    "Tax_Registration_Number": "16664159",
    "Blue_River_No": null,
    "Contact": [
      "Ms. Rana Elayyan"
    ],
    "Brand": "Mercedes ",
    "OOH_price_list": {
      "Net_Total": "16575.000",
      "Grand_Total": "19227.000",
      "Sales_Tax": "16.00",
      "Total": "19500.000",
      "DIscount": "15.00",
      "Amount_in_Words": "Nineteen Thousand Two Hundred Twenty Seven"
    },
    "BR_price_list": null,
    "blue_river_list": [],
    "Financial_Accountant_Name": "",
    "Select_Customer_Type": "Agency",
    "No_Of_Faces_Production": null,
    "No of Faces": "100",
    "Sales Person Name": "**"
  },
  {
    "ID": "OOH.2m2.2024.7.9999",
    "OOH_media_list": [
      {
        "Network": "Flawless C",
        "Amount": "5250.000",
        "Duration": "1 week",
        "of_Faces": "25",
        "Start_Date": "30-Jul-2024",
        "End_Date": "05-Aug-2024",
        "type": "Out_Of_Home",
        "Delivery Date": "30-Jul-2024"
      },
      {
        "Network": "Velvet Booster B",
        "Amount": "14250.000",
        "Duration": "1 week",
        "of_Faces": "75",
        "Start_Date": "31-Jul-2024",
        "End_Date": "06-Aug-2024",
        "type": "Out_Of_Home",
        "Delivery Date": "31-Jul-2024"
      }
    ],
    "Email": "ABC@gmail.com",
    "Category": [],
    "Sales Person Email": "",
    "Contract Number": null,
    "Client Name": "MindShare",
    "Sector": null,
    "Financial_Accountant_Email": "",
    "Tax_Registration_Number": "16664159",
    "Blue_River_No": null,
    "Contact": [
      "Ms. Rana Elayyan"
    ],
    "Brand": "Mercedes ",
    "OOH_price_list": {
      "Net_Total": "16575.000",
      "Grand_Total": "19227.000",
      "Sales_Tax": "16.00",
      "Total": "19500.000",
      "DIscount": "15.00",
      "Amount_in_Words": "Nineteen Thousand Two Hundred Twenty Seven"
    },
    "BR_price_list": null,
    "blue_river_list": [],
    "Financial_Accountant_Name": "",
    "Select_Customer_Type": "Agency",
    "No_Of_Faces_Production": null,
    "No of Faces": "100",
    "Sales Person Name": "**"
  }
]




